# событие на нажатие кнопки

Tags: javascript, php

как отправлять на сервер набор из 10 символов (напр.1234567890) по нажатию на кнопку методом post.Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант

```
<?php
echo '<form action="test.php" method="post">';

echo '<input type="hidden" name="data" value="1234567890">';

echo '<input type="submit" value="Отправить">';
echo '</form>';


if(isset($_POST['data'])){

$var=$_POST['data'];

echo '<br>';
print_r($var);

}
?>
```

Comment: а чтобы он автоматом нажимался перед <?php ставится <body onLoad="document.getElementById('sbm').click()"> это обработчик кнопки, но некоторые браузеры блокируют данное действие ps поставить id="sbm"  возле type="submit"

Comment: Зачем форму "эхать"?

Comment: да просто, привык так уже)

Comment: @РустамГимранов https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=108&v=LAxtOgacyVM&feature=emb_logo

Comment: Плохая привычка, хотя бы с точки зрения подсветки кода.

Comment: сделал просмотр html кода разницы не увидел